# Datatable isnt updating back to sql

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, datatable

I have two datagridview (viewa, viewb). I pass rows viewa to viewb by clicking and edit in viawb. I can get items to viewa from server but I cant update datatable back. Currently I m trying with this with one dgv. appreciated if you can atleast direct me.

```
                public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand();
    DataTable data = new DataTable();
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection();
        conn.ConnectionString = "server=server.server.com;user=testuser;pwd=password;database=test";
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand();
        command.Connection = conn;
        command.CommandText = "select * from malzeme";
        DataTable data = new DataTable();
        SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
        adapter.Fill(data);
        dataGridView1.DataSource = data;
    }

    private void save_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            string connectionString= "server=server.server.com;user=testuser;pwd=password;database=test";


            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
                adapter.UpdateCommand = new SqlCommand("UPDATE malzeme SET malzemekodu=@malzemekodu " + "WHERE Id=@Id", conn);

                adapter.Update(data);
            }

           }


        catch
        {
        }
    }
}
```

here is the example of dgv https://i.stack.imgur.com/7whSK.png

Comment: Did you finish to type your code?

Comment: yes, I did unfortunately it doenst work

Answer (score 0):

From the incomplete code you've provided, it looks like you aren't defining the InsertCommand/UpdateCommand/DeleteCommand properties of the SqlDataAdapter. If you don't tell it how to update your database it won't know how... here's a link that will help you understand better how to use the SqlDataAdapter for updating your database: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308055 . Good luck!

**EDIT**
You need to populate the parameters in your command text:

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("UPDATE malzeme SET malzemekodu=@malzemekodu WHERE Id=@Id", conn);
    //  Add parameters to the command to replace the parameter tokens in your command text
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@malzemekodu", "someValue"));
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Id", "someId"));

    adapter.UpdateCommand = cmd; 

    adapter.Update(data);
}
```

Comment: @emmett I hope this helps clarify.

Comment: Thanks. but it didnt sadly . Do we need to create UPDATE trigger to the table?

Comment: No, update triggers are for something different. After you added the parameters as I showed in my code sample, what happened? Do you get an exception? What values are you putting in for the parameters, and where are you getting those values?

Comment: added before your code "data = (DataTable)(dataGridView1.DataSource);" and I'm getting exception  "Must declare the scalar variable "@id""